# JavaFx - Dynamic JXML, add Pane element on Initialize

Tags: java, oop, javafx, controller, fxml

i am new in JavaFX, and as any newcomer, i am flood with doubts.
So i have to populate an `<AnchorPane>` with children `<Pane>` like this FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="anchor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <!-- Add multiple Panels here-->
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane anchor;
    @FXML javafx.scene.layout.Pane pane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        pane.prefHeight(100);
        pane.prefWidth(300);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: aqua");

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            anchor.getChildren().add(pane);
            pane.setLayoutY(i*100);
        }
    }

}
```

Hope someone can help me... Thank You!!

Comment: Any UI-Object can only be shown once. If you need to show something multiple times you have to create a instance of it everytime you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for it is...

The FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0">
         <content>
            <GridPane fx:id="gridPane"  prefHeight="410.0" prefWidth="294.0"></GridPane>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The Controller Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private GridPane gridPane;

    private Pane paneContainer;
    private Label paneLabel;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {

            paneLabel = new Label();
            paneLabel.setText("it is..." + i);

            paneContainer = new Pane();
            paneContainer.setStyle("-fx-background-color: aqua; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 1px; -fx-border-color:#000; ");
            paneContainer.setPrefWidth(200);
            paneContainer.setPrefHeight(100);

            paneContainer.getChildren().add(paneLabel);
            gridPane.add(paneContainer, 0, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Use GridPane is the easiest way to do it!